# Почему в UE4 в метод SpawnActor нужно передавать объект, а не его адрес памяти, в то время как метод имеет в параметре указатель?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4, аргументы

В UE4 у класса **UWorld** есть шаблонный метод **SpawnActor**, одна из перегрузок которого имеет следующие параметры:

```
template<class T>
T* SpawnActor(UClass* Class, FTransform const& Transform,const FActorSpawnParameters& SpawnParameters = FActorSpawnParameters())
```

Для его вызова я создаю локальные переменные, которые намереваюсь туда передать:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
TSubclassOf<AActor> spawnActor;

FRotator rotation(0, 0, 0);
FVector position(0, 0, 0);
FVector scale(1, 1, 1);
FTransform transform(rotation, position, scale);
```

И собственно пытаюсь вызвать метод **SpawnActor**:

```
GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AActor>(&spawnActor,transform);
```

Его вызов не происходит из - за того, что я пытаюсь передать адрес объекта **spawnActor** (**но почему?** в параметрах метод же имеет указатель, а не ссылку).

При попытке вписать в качестве аргумента - объект (а не его адрес) метод успешно выполняет свою работу:

```
GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AActor>(spawnActor,transform);
```

Почему в данном случае необходимо вписать в метод в качестве аргумента именно объект, а не его адрес в то время, как метод имеет в качестве параметра указатель (UClass* Class)?

Comment: `TSubclassOf<AActor>` - не тип экземпляра `AActor`, а своего рода умный **указатель**. Соответственно он умеет приводится к обычному указателю на тип: `AActor *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В TSubclassOf есть оператор преобразования на тип UClass*:

```
FORCEINLINE operator TClassType* () const
{
    return **this;
}
```